# Как правильно написать в данном случае: "не много" или "немного"?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать фразу: *Не много юрист, не много бухгалтер, но пока, больше всего мама.*

Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

**Немного юрист, немного бухгалтер, но пока больше всего мама.** Можно поставить авторское интонационное тире после *пока*.

НЕМНОГО. I. нареч.  3. **В некоторой степени; чуть-чуть, слегка.** Н. хромать, заикаться. Н. загореть, рассердиться, устать. Суп надо н. посолить. Юбку надо н. укоротить.

Это наречие, можно заменить синонимом (в некоторой степени)., слитное написание приставки НЕ. Наречие относится к существительному, парная отрицательная конструкция не существует.

Для сравнения (выбор формы написания НЕ): **Не много ты у нас поработал.** Это отрицание. **Он немного (некоторое время) поработал у нас, потом ушёл.** (утверждение).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но разве в предложении нет отрицания по смыслу? Не много поработала юристом, не много поработала бухгалтером, а больше всего работаю мамой. Например. Почему не много юрист, потому что сейчас мама . Юрист по смыслу отрицается, из-за второй части, потому, что мама в данный момент . Я запуталась со смыслом и мне кажется, что оно отрицательное.

Comment: По смыслу, домохозяйка и юрист является противопоставлением, нет?

Comment: «Много работать юристом» можно, но что такое «много юрист»? Не здесь ли путаница началась?

Comment: Не много юрист , а больше домохозяйка. Т.е. Не много юрист( подразумевается "а мало юрист") , потому, что домохозяйка

Comment: Нет сочетаний "много юрист , много бухгалтер", поэтому отрицать нечего. Для сравнения: сочетания "много работать, немного работать" существуют, поэтому есть и вариант с отрицанием "не много работать".Юристом, бухгалтером работаю не много, пока больше всего мама.

Comment: «Нет сочетания "много юрист"»? Если нет, то почему оно в Вашем вопросе? По какому случаю отрываете НЕ от  МНОГО? Не сравнивайте с «много работать юристом», — правильны лишь формулы: не много, а мало; не мало, а много. И не противопоставляйте домохозяйку и юриста. Начните с последнего.

Comment: А если оставить как есть, мне кажется так художественнее )), (это не для работодателя), по смыслу возможно оставить частицу "не" отдельно?  Немного актриса, немного спортсмен, немного художник , так ведь говорят и для этих слов нет вариантов написания частицы "не" отдельно?

Comment: Но в формуле "не много, а мало " , "а" может подразумеваться , исходя из смысла второй части предложения. Насколько я знаю, "а" может либо писаться, либо подразумеваться по смыслу . Не совсем поняла про то , что бы начать с последнего .

Comment: А еще, если фразы "много юрист" нет, то нельзя , наверное, применить правило, в котором сказано, что если можно "немного" заменить на "много" или "мало" , то "не" пишется слитно. Например, "немного/не много юрист" не тоже самое , что "немного подождал " или "немного яблок"

Comment: Он  немного (= в некоторой степени) юрист - это нормальное сочетание, а много юрист/не много юрист - таких сочетаний нет.  Есть в грамматике такие понятия, как стандартные отрицательные и утвердительные конструкции, ими и надо пользоваться. Здесь дело не в противопоставлении, а в градации признака: много - не много (среднее количество) - немного (небольшое количество) - мало, так изменяется количественный ряд.  Или, к примеру,  строим по смыслу другой ряд: Он очень странный -  странный -  немного странный

Comment: А еще) возможно, тут как сказать."Ты бухгалтер и юрист?"-" Да, немного юрист и немного бухгалтер  "  или " Ты опытный юрист и бухгалтер ?"-"Нет, я не много(а мало, всмысле была/есть) юрист и  не много бухгалтер , потому, что 6 лет в декрете ".. ну, не знаю можно ли так сказать

Comment: Нет, так не говорят и не пишут. "Не много" услышат как "немного", а на письме посчитают за  ошибку.

Comment: Ну а в теории можно так сказать ? Понятно, что не распространено и посчитают за ошибку, но мне важно знать допустимо так сказать и написать или нет , хотя бы в теории.

Comment: Да какая там теория? Немного -  наречие со значением чуть-чуть, слегка, в некоторой степени. Образует сочетания с  глаголами, прилагательными и редко с существительными. (не путать: немного воды, это уже числительное). Можно сказать: немного (в некоторой степени) юрист. А вот наречие много с существительными вообще не сочетается (см. словарь), нельзя сказать "много юрист", (не путать: много юристов, это числительное). ВОТ ВАМ И ВСЯ ТЕОРИЯ.

Comment: Теперь все понятно, спасибо!